# Rest based web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, wcf, rest

REST is concerned with specifying how a remote client can interface with a server, not how the server goes about its job of actually satisfying the clients' requests. Does that mean that if I make a Rest based web service using WCF I can still go about normal database querys in the same fashion without worrying its not rest based? For instance select, insert, update, delete etc?

Comment: I can't answer specifically.  Are you asking can you emulate/expose the normal database query API via web services such that client applications can essentially run queries directly on the database?  I suppose you could, but it probably wouldn't be a good idea from a security perspective.  Usually you expose services to perform certain, specific high-level actions which then separates your database implementation and provides security from malicious/improper use.  Also, I'm probably completely misunderstanding the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internals of a web service is of no concern to the consumer of the service. As long as your public interface sticks to REST principles, internal details are all up to you.

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't have to do anything with your database queries. It is how client communicates with the server.